# Sulu cmf get referrer

Tags: php, sulu

I have two pages in my content tree n sulu 1.0.13. On page "A" I set a reference to page "B" with a field of the content type "single internal link".

When I am on page "B" I want to get the referring page "A". I have tried following code in my controller:

```
$dm  = $this->get('sulu_document_manager.document_manager');
$doc = $dm->find('992758cf-1da4-4e45-9ee4-ca9c4ec3998e'); // UUID of page "B"
$di  = $this->get('sulu_document_manager.document_inspector');
$node = $di->getNode($doc);

$refs = $di->getReferrers($doc); // $refs is an empty collection
$refs = $node->getReferences(); // $refs is an empty collection
$refs = $node->getWeakReferences(); // $refs is an empty collection
```

$refs is always an empty collection.

What is the right way to get the referring page?

Update: I now use version 1.1.0 RC2

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.  Please describe your issue more clearly and show an attempt to solve the problem on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly the `SingleInternalLink` content type is currently just saving the UUID as a string, and not as a proper reference in PHPCR. This is also described in this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/sulu-io/sulu/issues/545). I will reevaluate this issue, and see if we can fix that in the near future.

As a workaround you could use the `InternalLinks` content type, which already saves its values as references, although it is possible to add more than one link.

Comment: I have tried InternalLinks and now it works, But I get two elements if I call `$refs = $di->getReferrers($doc);`. One of type `Sulu\Bundle\ContentBundle\Document\RouteDocument` and the other one of type  `Sulu\Bundle\ContentBundle\Document\PageDocument`.

Comment: I have the issue with version 1.1.0 RC2

Comment: Yeah, the issue isn't fixed yet in any version... And that's right, I didn't think about that... You probably have to check if the document is from type `PageDocument`. Routes have its own tree, and are also referencing pages, this is why you get two referrers.